# Formula Fields not appearing to be added to reports

Tags: custom-report-type

I have a custom Object Patient which has formula fields like- Date of First Application, Date of Last Application.

I am creating a report - Patient with cases. In this, i am unable to find these formula fields in the field list (left most corner)

Comment: Are you using custom report type?

Comment: Please check your field level security for that profile even if you are an admin. If those fields are not accessible then certainly you won't see them. Hope this helps